# very very hard Query and group by columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table as follows:

```
A----B----C----D----F----E
1----2----3-----4----5----6
1----2----3-----4----5----6
1----2----3-----4----5----6
```

Now I want to make a query that table to table below lead the field values c, d of the following columns A, B, the values in column F, E the following columns A, B,

```
A----B
1----2
1----2
1----2
3----4
3----4
3----4
5----6
5----6
5----6
```

now group by A columns and sum B columns.

The final table

```
A----B
1----6
3----12
5----18
```

Comment: Could you re-write your question more clearly?   I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Is this sql server or mysql. You tagged them both and they are NOT the same thing. Also, this isn't as hard as you think. You have 3 distinct results here and each result set is a simple aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Cross apply` to `unpivot` the data then find the `sum`

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (A INT,B INT,C INT,D INT,F INT,E INT)

INSERT #test
VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6),
       (1,2,3,4,5,6),
       (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

To get the first result use `Cross Apply` to convert your **column into rows**

```
SELECT data A,
       cname B
FROM   #test
       CROSS apply (VALUES(b,a),
                          (d,c),
                          (e,f)) ca (cname, data) order by A
```

**Which should result**

```
A   B
--  --
1   2
1   2
1   2
3   4
3   4
3   4
5   6
5   6
5   6
```

Then from the above result just use Aggregate `Sum` to find the sum of `B` grouped by `A`

```
SELECT data A,
       Sum(cname) B
FROM   #test
       CROSS apply (VALUES(b,a),
                          (d,c),
                          (e,f)) ca (cname, data)
GROUP  BY data
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
+==+==+
|A |B |
+==+==+
|1 |6 |
|3 |12|
|5 |18|
+==+==+
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this would do the trick:

```
SELECT A, SUM(B) AS B
FROM (
    SELECT A, B FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C, D FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT E, F FROM yourtable
) subquery
ORDER BY A
GROUP BY A
```

the subquery/union stuff converts your 6-column layout to a 2-column, then the outer query does grouping/summing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `group by` query on your previous answer:

```
select a, sum(b) as b
from (<previous query here>) a
group by a;
```